# Byobu - CentOS - Turning off window auto-renaming

Tags: centos, tmux, byobu

Window name shows the current directory path. If we rename the window name, then whenever we change a path in that window, the name always reverts back to the current directory path.
I tried updating `set-window-option -g automatic-rename on` to `set-window-option -g automatic-rename off` in `/usr/share/byobu/profile/tmux` with no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the config `set-window-option -g automatic-rename off`
doesn't work. When I added the following configuration:

```
set-option -g allow-rename off
```

in `/usr/share/byobu/profiles/tmux`, automatic renaming was turned off.

Comment: the file might be /usr/share/byobu/profiles/tmux? it is profiles instead of profile?